# How do i get a specific process name memory usage?

Tags: c#, winforms, performancecounter

I tried this code:

```
public static string GetProcessMemoryUsage(string processName)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                PerformanceCounter performanceCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
                performanceCounter.CategoryName = "Process";
                performanceCounter.CounterName = "Working Set";
                performanceCounter.InstanceName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
                processName = ((uint)performanceCounter.NextValue() / 1024).ToString(processName);
                return processName;
            }
        }
```

If the process name is for example: BFBC2Game
Then the method GetProcessMemoryUsage return me just the name: BFBC2Game
I want it to return me the memory usage value number like in Task Manager in windows for example when i run the task manager i see on BFBC2Game: 78% and 198.5MB memory usage.

Thats what i want to get in the returned string processName: 78% and 198.5MB 
Something like that. And that it iwll get update all the time in the loop. The same as it is in the task manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
var workingSet = (uint)performanceCounter.NextValue() / 1024;
return workingSet.ToString();
```

When you use [`UInt32.ToString(processName)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6h6txff8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) then process name is treated as format string for number. So, you have format string like `"Notepad.exe"`. It does not have placeholders for numbers, so result equals to format string value, i.e. process name.

Note - assigning memory usage value to `processName` variable is **very** confusing. I'd suggest to return `uint` value from this method:

```
public static uint GetProcessMemoryUsageInKilobytes(string processName)
{
    var performanceCounter = 
        new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Working Set", processName);
    return (uint)performanceCounter.NextValue() / 1024;
}
```

Or even simply use [`Process.WorkingSet64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.workingset64) to get amount of memory allocated to process.

Comment: Sergey and where do i use or how the variable processName ? I mean how do i get the uint for specific process name ?

Comment: @user3681442 pass process name as instance name of performance counter

Comment: Sergey it's working but how do i show it in MB's ? And how do i make it to be update more often like in task manager ? In task amanager i see 198.5MB while in the method i see 225340 . (Edited my question with what i did i used while(true))

Comment: @user3681442 I rolled back your edit. Question should be short and very specific. You should not write whole program within single question. If you have other problems, ask new questions. If question is answered, then mark it as accepted. Btw calculating size in MBs requires another division by 1024. Also if you don't want rounded result, then don't use `uint` - let it be float number. Another note - your loop makes no sense - you will exit this method on return